# Order by in SQL by DESC and ASC

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

So I've been doing this all night - can't quite understand my homework, and sadly my professor is unavailable on the weekend. Could anyone please help me on how I should go about it and what the final query would look like.
I really appreciated the help.

The salaries of each employee have been stored in the EMPLOYEE table.
Write a query to print the ID and the NAME of each of the three highest-earning employees
Print the NAME's in descending order by the SALARY, 
then ascending order by ID for matching SALARY

Comment: there are so many samples for famous employee table's salary ranking. First of all we expect you to show your effort tried so far.As a hint you can look up analytic functions.

Comment: Yes currently I'm a complete novice and most books on SQL seem to teach the theory only. Any suggestions on what I could do to solve such questions by myself in the future? ANy book recommendation?

Comment: [The questions seeking recommendations for books, software libraries, or other off-site resources are off-topic](https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3660/should-questions-asking-for-product-service-data-and-learning-course-book-w)

Answer (score 0):

This is Scott's EMP table adjusted to your situation; `order by` clause already shows desired result, which would be the first 4 rows because two employees (Scott and Ford) have the same salary.

```
SQL> select * From employee order by salary desc, id asc;

        ID NAME           SALARY
---------- ---------- ----------
      7839 KING             5000
      7788 SCOTT            3000
      7902 FORD             3000
      7566 JONES            2975
      7698 BLAKE            2850
      7782 CLARK            2450
      7499 ALLEN            1600
      7844 TURNER           1500
      7934 MILLER           1300
      7521 WARD             1250
      7654 MARTIN           1250
      7876 ADAMS            1100
      7900 JAMES             950
      7369 SMITH             800

14 rows selected.
```

Therefore, using `DENSE_RANK` analytic function, you get the result:

```
SQL> with emps as
  2    (select id, name, salary,
  3            dense_rank() over (order by salary desc) rnk
  4     from employee
  5    )
  6  select id, name, salary
  7  from emps
  8  where rnk <= 3
  9  order by salary desc, id asc;

        ID NAME           SALARY
---------- ---------- ----------
      7839 KING             5000
      7788 SCOTT            3000
      7902 FORD             3000
      7566 JONES            2975

SQL>
```

**[EDIT: a not that *advanced* approach]**

Another option is to use inline views, two of them, nested. Why? Because you have to sort rows first, then fetch rownum which represents *sort order* and return rows whose `rn <= 3`.

As you can see, as opposed to the previous (analytic function) query, this option can't handle "duplicate" salaries.

```
SQL> select id, name, salary, rn
  2  from (select id, name, salary, rownum rn
  3        from (select id, name, salary
  4              from employee
  5              order by salary desc, id asc
  6             )
  7       )
  8  where rn <= 3
  9  order by salary desc, id asc;

        ID NAME           SALARY         RN
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
      7839 KING             5000          1
      7788 SCOTT            3000          2
      7902 FORD             3000          3

SQL>
```

Comment: Thanks so much, for the help, but it seems this level of query design is beyond me right now. Any suggestions on how to get better?

Comment: This **is** better. I've edited my answer and added some more code; have a look.